# Looking for a recurrence relation ot combinatorial way to calculate initial number

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

A flock of birds migrating south flies above seven lakes. Half of the birds in the flock, plus half a bird(I'm guessing the initial flock contained an odd number of birds, say 5, so in the first lake $\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{2} =3$ left), are leaving the flock- wanting to lend in the lake below. After the seventh lake is passed- there are no birds left in the flock.
Find how many birds started the journey.
What I did:
I denoted the initial number of birds with $n$ and the calculated how many birds left for each lake. It was something like that: $$(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{n-(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2})}{2}+\frac{1}{2})...$$ Assuming I could sum this up and then do something, but it's way to tidious a nd naive.
Can I do it more logically, smarter and more importantly faster?
Maybe a recursion?
Any tips/hint will be welcomed.

Comment: how can a "half" bird leave the flock ?.

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing the initial flock contained an odd number of birds, say 5, so in the first lake $\frac{5}{2} +\frac{1}{2} =3$ left.

Comment: then you should have mentioned that.

Comment: Okay, I just thought that I could ask the same question but with a father giving money to his children, and it will be the same, so the "half" didn't seemed to be important. But I'm editing the post just for the sake of clearity

Answer (score 0):

Just start with the last lake: Let $n_i$ be the number of birds left before coming to the $i$-th lake (so $n_0$ is the total number of birds). In other words $n_I$
 is the number of birds that fly between lake $i-1$ and lake $i$. Obviously $n_8 = 0$ since there were no birds left. But

$n_8 = n_7 - (n_7/2 +1/2)$ (the half of $n_7$ plus a half left at the $7$-nth sea, so $n_7$ minus that number is still left. This recursion holds also for the rest:

$n_{i+1} = n_i - (n_i/2+1/2) = (n_i-1)/2$.

So $n_8 = 0 \implies n_7 = 1 \implies n_6 = 3 \implies \ldots$

(And I recommend trying to find an explicit formula for this sequence. Perhaps just number the indices in reverse, that might make it easier.)